# Three.js - Light doesn't work on texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a simple solar system with three.js, I have finished everything, now I want to add some shading, but apparently it doesn't work when working on textures.

```
loader.load("earth.jpg", function ( texture ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 20, 20 ),
        material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: texture,
            overdraw: true,
        }),
        mesh     = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    group.add( mesh );
});
```

If I replace `map: texture` with `color: 0xffffff` it works very well, but when I add a texture, the light shading disappears.

Why lights doesn't works on textures?

Maybe should I create two spheres for every planet? One with a texture and another transparent with shadow?

Comment: Are you using `CanvasRenderer`?

Comment: Yes, should I use WebGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`. It does not support `MeshLambertMaterial` and diffuse textures in combination.

You will have to switch to `WebGLRenderer.`

three.js r.65